# Algorithm for immediate string search in a number of text files

Tags: search, full-text-search

I'm writing a help system and I would like to implement the search in modern way, like e.g. it works now in Google search: when user only starts to type in query letters he immediately gets the result and each next letter makes the result set more specific.

What are the algorithms for indexing text and searching it this way?

Wikipedia or/and other links will be fine, no need to waste your time to detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As a practical approach, I think you may use some library like [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) which will help you with most of the things about full text indexing.